# Prevent particular child element from firing parent's mouseover event in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have parent element which has mouseover event handler implemented using `.mouseover()` in Jquery.

It has 2 child elements, one contains image element, and second contains description element which has absolute position. On parent `mouseover` description slides on the image element.

Simplified version of code for the project would look like this:

```js
$('.main-parent').mouseenter(function(){
 $(this).addClass('item-hovered');
}).mouseleave(function(){
 $(this).removeClass('item-hovered');
});
```

```css
.main-parent {
    position: relative;
}

.child-description {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2em;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -45%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 350ms;
}

.item-hovered .child-description {
    bottom: 10%;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 350ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-parent">
    <div class="child-image">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="child-description">
        <h4 class="title">Title</h4>
        <p class="subtitle">Subtitle</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum paragraph...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

As expected, `.child-description` is firing `mouseover` bind to `.main-parent` element, as it is its child and a part of it.

Is there a way to ignore `.child-description` element so that it doesn't fire function on `mouseover` event. The thing is before you `hover` the element, it is bellow the image made "invisible" to user using `opacity: 0;`, but it still can be hovered and used to fire `mouseover` of parent element.

I haven't find answer for this particular solution on stackoverflow, and if there is let me know. I appreciate your help :)

Comment: by the way, adding `overflow:hidden;` to your `main-parent` class, and redefine your selector `.item-hovered .child-description` in `.main-parent:hover .child-description` (with pseudo-class hover) can avoid you the javascript (jquery) part in this case.

Comment: Actually @scraaappy, after some experimenting I did that and it is working, added overflow:hidden; to parent and child outside the element box of parent is not triggering ```mouseenter``` anymore, but still have needed same code for other purposes. Thank you for the tip :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check whether child-description is the target of the event

```
     $('.main-parent').mouseenter(function (e) {
        if (!$(e.target).hasClass('child-description')) {
            $(this).addClass('item-hovered');
        }
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('item-hovered');
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Ercan, this is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you would intercept the event for that child and then call [`event.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) and [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) as shown below.

Also, JQuery no longer recommends event shortcut methods, like `mouseenter`. Instead, they suggest using [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```js
$(".child-description").on("mouseover", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();  // Cancel the event for this element
  event.stopPropagation(); // Prevent the event from propagating to other elements
});

$('.main-parent').on("mouseenter", function(){
 $(this).addClass('item-hovered');
}).on("mouseleave", function(){
 $(this).removeClass('item-hovered');
});
```

```css
.main-parent {
    position: relative;
}

.child-description {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2em;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -45%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 350ms;
}

.item-hovered .child-description {
    bottom: 10%;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 350ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-parent">
    <div class="child-image">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="child-description">
        <h4 class="title">Title</h4>
        <p class="subtitle">Subtitle</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum paragraph...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Scott for the working solution, I upvoted it, but I chose Ercan solution with if statement, because It is more versatile in my actual implementation on project. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Trying adding the following css rule to `.child-description`.

`pointer-events: none;`

```
.child-description {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2em;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -45%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 350ms;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.item-hovered .child-description {
  bottom: 10%;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 350ms;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

This should prevent the element from responding to any mouse events. You will have to swap `pointer-events: none;` for `pointer-events: auto;` once you want the element to register interactions.

https://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

Comment: But what if the OP wants the element to respond to a `click` event? This is a solution to a different question than is being asked.

Comment: Based on my understanding of the problem, my solution should work. A click event will still register if `pointer-events: auto` is set on the hovered state of `.child-description`

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you on your answer. It is working solution, but as Scott mentioned I will be needing element to receive ```click``` event, so I chose solution from Ercan with ```if``` statement.

Answer (score 1):

I see some interesting answers here, so, I thought I would offer my own.

Why not use `event.target` and (in this particular case) `event.target.className`?  [Sample JSBIN Demo Online](https://jsbin.com/cilosiy/edit?html,output)

For instance...

```
$('.main-parent').mouseover(function(e) {
  if(e.target.className == 'subtitle') {
    console.log("Child mouseover!");
    return;  // child mouseover, ignore
  }

  console.log("Parent mouseover!");

  return true;  // parent mouseover, activate some behavior
});
```

The advantage here should be observable -- you have quick, easy control of the paths of logic in relatively little code.

Comment: Thanks on answering. I actually used similar code with ```event.target``` and it is working as expected :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to prevent this using the `stopPropagation` method:

```
$('.child-description').on("mouseenter mouseleave", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```